# AttributeError when trying to find coefficients of series using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Just trying to find the coefficients of this series using SympPy, however I get an AttributeError.

```
from pip import main
from sympy import series, Symbol, sympify, Poly, cos, sin, tan, oo
from sympy.abc import a, n, s, x, y, z
import numpy as np    


f = tan(x)

print("\nExample Series:")
series_f1 = series(f, x, 2, 6, "+")
print(series_f1)

coeff = series_f1.all_coeffs()

print("\nCoefficients:")
print(coeff)
```

Here is the error. I get the expansion that I want but no luck in extracting the coefficients whatsoever.

```
Example Series:
tan(2) + (1 + tan(2)**2)*(x - 2) + (x - 2)**2*(tan(2)**3 + tan(2)) + (x - 2)**3*(1/3 + 4*tan(2)**2/3 + tan(2)**4) + (x - 2)**4*(tan(2)**5 + 5*tan(2)**3/3 + 2*tan(2)/3) + (x - 2)**5*(2/15 + 17*tan(2)**2/15 + 2*tan(2)**4 + tan(2)**6) + O((x - 2)**6, (x, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bumblev/Quantum-Ergodic-Processes/new/PowerSeries.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/bumblev/Quantum-Ergodic-Processes/new/PowerSeries.py", line 24, in main
    coeff = series_f1.all_coeffs()
AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'all_coeffs'
```

Comment: Why did you expect that it has a method `all_coeffs`?

Comment: My math education was long ago, but I don't recall the term "coeffecient" being used for simple addition...

Comment: im trying to find the coefficients of a power series, but used tan(x) as a simpler function to work with first.

Comment: You printed `series_f1`.  Why didn't you show it, or at least part of it?  And check its `type`.  What are coefficients that you expect?  With respect to which variable?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the object returned by `series` into a `Poly`

```py
from sympy import *
# ...
coeff = series_f1.as_poly(tan(2)).all_coeffs()
```